# GCP stored procedure to access nested columns and perform a calculation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stored-procedures, google-bigquery, nested, dynamic-sql

Is there a way to create a procedure that will parse columns with nested fields in order to perform a calculation for all columns (even nested ones)?

My issue is that this procedure stays on the first level and performs my calculation only there without parsing dynamically my nested columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `myprocedurename`(
   _tableName STRING,
   _destination STRING
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE _columns STRING;
  DECLARE _sql STRING;

  SET _columns = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
      CASE
        WHEN field_path = column_name THEN CONCAT("ROUND(COUNTIF(", column_name, " IS NOT NULL) * 100.0 / COUNT(*), 2) AS completude_", column_name) -- Handle top-level columns
        ELSE CONCAT("ROUND(COUNTIF(", REPLACE(field_path, '.', '_'), " IS NOT NULL) * 100.0 / COUNT(*), 2) AS completude_", REPLACE(field_path, '.', '_')) -- Handle nested fields (but it takes into consideration only the top level of the nested columns)
      END, ', ')
    FROM `myproject.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
    WHERE table_name = _tableName);

  SET _sql = CONCAT("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mydataset.", _destination, "` AS SELECT ", _columns, " FROM `mydataset.", _tableName, "`");

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE _sql;
END;
```